# openURL not work in Action Extension

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

I add following code:

```
- (IBAction)done {
    // Return any edited content to the host app.
    // This template doesn't do anything, so we just echo the passed in items.

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"lister://today"];
    [self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        NSLog(@"fun=%s after completion. success=%d", __func__, success);
    }];
    [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:self.extensionContext.inputItems completionHandler:nil];

}
```

after I create the Action Extension target. But it can not work.

My purpose is that: when user view a photo in Photos.app (the iOS's default Photos.app or called gallery), and he click the share button to launch our extension view.
We can transfer the image from Photos.app to my own app and deal or upload the image in my app.

I also try "CFBundleDocumentTypes" but it also can not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [openURL from Today Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356314/openurl-from-today-extension)

Comment: You must also add a URL Scheme in the app's info/properties area. See documentation for "inter app communication" and "Using URL Schemes to Communicate with Apps". <posted for future searchers>

Comment: Hi, I'm using tableviewcontroller but not able to use extensionContext in this class. can some one plz help me on this

Comment: For anyone looking for more clarification; Apple is pretty clear in the docs around what can and cannot open URLs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2). The relevant text from that doc: `A Today widget (and no other app extension type) can ask the system to open its containing app by calling the openURL:completionHandler: method of the NSExtensionContext class.` An interesting workaround is below in the comments.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is by design. We don't want Custom Actions to become app launchers.

Comment: It seems that this is also true for Share Extensions. Can you confirm? I was trying to launch to the shared content after it successfully posted. Is there any way to provide the user with confirmation the share succeeded?

Comment: Are you a Apple staff? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Is there confirmed statements from Apple regarding when "openURL" will and will not be allowed?  I would like to use it in a Share and/or Action Extension only to the containing app's URL scheme.  There are many valid applications for this that enable an extension to stay light, and still give the user the option to jump to the containing app if advanced options are required.

Comment: It works in Today View Extensions under certain circumstances. That's it for now.

Comment: The app launcher thing makes sense. however, It seems there's a functionality hole here were it would be useful to provide a specific API for launching the container app since there is a guaranteed extension to container app relationship.

Comment: So other than sending something to the internet, Share extensions are effectively useless?

Comment: this seems to contradict Apple's own documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2

Comment: Any new information on the workaround proposed by nurne?

Comment: @Jesse Your suggestion is correct. Since Apple change the document and it says, "The dotted line in Figure 2-2 represents the limited interaction available between an app extension and its containing app. A Today widget (and no other app extension type) can ask the system to open its containing app by calling the openURL:completionHandler: method of the NSExtensionContext class. " This answer looks OK up to now.[https://developer.apple.com/...](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2)

Comment: If share extension , openURL method is not called anymore, So what would be workaround to open files and process from gmail, google drive etc in main app ? Any way so far ?

Answer (score 44):

This is what I used to do:

```
UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
NSString *urlString = @"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/watuu/id304697459";
NSString * content = [NSString stringWithFormat : @"<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=%@'></head>", urlString];
[webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

Please note that in this case I am instantiating this call from the UIInputViewController.

This method should also work using the URL scheme from the containing app

**UPDATE 04/17/2015: This does not work with iOS 8.3. We are looking for a solution and we will update the answer soon**

**UPDATE 06/01/2015: We found a solution that works in iOS 8.3**

```
var responder = self as UIResponder?

while (responder != nil){
    if responder!.respondsToSelector(Selector("openURL:")) == true{
        responder!.callSelector(Selector("openURL:"), object: url, delay: 0)
    }
    responder = responder!.nextResponder()
}
```

This will find a suitable responder to send the openURL to.

You need to add this extension that replaces the performSelector for swift and helps in the construction of the mechanism:

```
extension NSObject {
    func callSelector(selector: Selector, object: AnyObject?, delay: NSTimeInterval) {
        let delay = delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector(selector, toTarget:self, withObject: object)
        })
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 06/15/2015: Objective-C**

Someone asked for the code in Objective-C so here it is. I am not going to run it as I don't have the time right now but it should be quite straightforward:

```
UIResponder *responder = self;
while(responder){
    if ([responder respondsToSelector: @selector(OpenURL:)]){
        [responder performSelector: @selector(OpenURL:) withObject: [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com" ]];
    }
    responder = [responder nextResponder];
}
```

As mentioned, I have not run this Objective-C code, it is just a conversion from the Swift code. Please let me know if you encounter any issues and the solution and I will update it. Nowadays, I am just using swift and unfortunately my brain is deprecating Objective-C

**UPDATE 05/02/2016: Deprecated functions**

As pointed by @KyleKIM the Selector functions have been replaced in Swift 2.2 by #selector. Also, there is a function that is deprecated and will probably get removed in Swift 3.0 so I am doing some research to find an alternative.

**UPDATE 09/16/2016: XCode 8, Swift 3.0 and iOS10**
The following code is still working on the mentioned versions. You will get some warnings:

```
let url = NSURL(string:urlString)
let context = NSExtensionContext()
context.open(url! as URL, completionHandler: nil)

var responder = self as UIResponder?

while (responder != nil){
    if responder?.responds(to: Selector("openURL:")) == true{
        responder?.perform(Selector("openURL:"), with: url)
    }
    responder = responder!.next
}
```

**UPDATE 6/15/2017: XCode 8.3.3**

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
let selectorOpenURL = sel_registerName("openURL:")
let context = NSExtensionContext()
context.open(url! as URL, completionHandler: nil)

var responder = self as UIResponder?

while (responder != nil){
    if responder?.responds(to: selectorOpenURL) == true{
        responder?.perform(selectorOpenURL, with: url)
    }
    responder = responder!.next
}
```

Comment: Yes. I am not the only one using it. Another keyboard extension in the store RIFFSY uses the same code.

Comment: burt also found [an issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657515/open-url-scheme-from-ios-extension) with ios 8.3

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander what is the issue? Please share

Comment: @JulioBailon Apple has restricted using any workarounds like UIWebView for iOS 8.3

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander have you found any ways of accomplishing that without UIWebView?

Comment: Has anyone found any ways of opening the container app from the keyboard?

Comment: @TomSawyer it works perfectly for me and for many others. Maybe I can help you if you give me some more details. Where are you running the code? Have you implemented the extension? My recommendation is to run it from the InputViewController itself

Comment: @rob1302 I will see what I can do. Stay put

Comment: @rob1302 I converted it to Objective-C, let me know if it works for you. I have not tested it.

Comment: @JulioBailon The code builds successfully and reaches inside `if ([responder respondsToSelector: @selector(openURL:)]){` however the line of  `[responder performSelector: @selector(openURL:) withObject: [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com" ]];` doesn't do anything

Comment: @rob1302 try removing the break from the while so it tries all the responders that can handle that selector. I introduced that break recently in one of the edits and that might be the issue.

Comment: @JulioBailon I tried removing the break...there's only 1 responder that gets in there anyways so removing the break did nothing. Appreciate the help either way

Comment: @JulioBailon So what this code actually does is that it looks for `UIApplication`, because that is the only object which implements `openURL`. Normally when you want to open URL from app, you use `sharedApplication` but it is annotated as not accessible from extensions. However iOS can't prevent you from looking it up in the responder chain. Neat.

Comment: I can say it seems to work in iOS 9 as well, but ask the user for confirmation before opening the app.

Comment: @PavelZdenek I thought the extension is running in a separate thread. How is it possible that it can get the instance of UIApplication?

Comment: @skyline75489 You are just moving up in the hierarchy of responders until you find one that can respond to that selector. Remember the difference between thread and process. The extension belongs to a process and that process has a UIResponder that can call openURL.

Comment: Iteration thru responders doesn't work for me. `[self nextResponder]` returns `nil`. I played a bit and if I start with `self.parentViewController` instead of `self` it *sometimes* works, e.g. doesn't work during the first share and does work later. I checked on iOS 9.2 (simulator and real device)

Comment: I am using Xcode7.3.1 GM, it gives me yellow warnings "Use '#selector' instead of explicitly constructing a 'Selector'  "  and suggesting to change Selector("openURL:") to #selector(UIApplication.openURL(_:)). Doing so occurs RED error 'opneURL' is unavailable.  with some digging I saw "Construction of Selector from string literals deprecated and will be removed in Swift 3.0". what should we do?

Comment: @KyleKIM good point. I am going to do some research and update the code. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Any update on alternatives for deprecated methods? Xcode8 is already out .

Comment: @AhmetAkkök we have submitted an extension for iOS10 in XCode8 and it still works with the following swift code:

    let url = NSURL(string:urlString)
    let context = NSExtensionContext()
    context.open(url! as URL, completionHandler: nil)
        
    var responder = self as UIResponder?
        
    while (responder != nil){
        if responder?.responds(to: Selector("openURL:")) == true{
            responder?.perform(Selector("openURL:"), with: url)
        }
        responder = responder!.next
    }

Comment: @Julio, I migrated from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3 and the solution works perfectly in Swift 3, thank you so much once again!

Comment: How to go to keyboards setting at iOS10? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388317/open-keyboards-settings-screen-in-ioss-settings-app-programmatically-from-anot

Comment: @AhmetAkkök not sure what this has to do with this post. Opening the settings from the keyboard does not sound like a good idea. It is nice but users may consider it intrusive and therefore Apple will reject it

Comment: it used to work with openURL before iOS 10, with in the Contaning app as well as in the Keyboard (in case of a function requires full access you could send user to the settings).

Comment: @AhmetAkkök I know, but I understand why Apple is not permitting it now. It is intrusive.

Comment: @Julio that may be the reason. I still hope it gets fixed. It is not easy to explain all the users how to add a new keyboard or give full access. Users need to go 4 menus under Settings 1- General 2- Keyboard, 3- Keyboards, 4- Add a new keyboard. It won't be necessary if Keyboard menu would be right under Settings

Comment: Hello... @Julio Bailon your answer helped me but there is one issue...can you please take a look on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019521/open-my-application-from-my-keyboard-extension-in-swift-3-0

Comment: Yes, worked...but I am afraid if this warning further raised as a issues or crashes. That's why I want to solve that. And one more reason is when I upload, Apple may reject app because of deprecated code.

Comment: @VRAwesome Apple does not reject deprecated code but you are right. It is something we need to find a better solution for.

Comment: @JulioBailon When I move to my app and come back to host app sometime (mostly second time) it shows blank screen. I am using Action extension.Can you please code on github. It will be really helpful thanks!!

Comment: You literally saved my app (which would be pointless without camera access during share action)

Comment: it seems like the solution from UPDATE 09/16/2016 is not working anymore (in Xcode 8.3.2)

Comment: @ndreisg Apple has been trying to avoid us from doing this for a while. I guess we will have to tweak it a little more again

Comment: Xcode 8.3.3 solution without warnings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44694703/557054

Comment: I'm a little confused. Does this work with an iMessage extension?? And would this code go into the container app or the extension? @JulioBailon

Comment: @illis69 it is working right now on a iMessage extension (WATUU) but it was compiled with a previous version of the SDK. Not sure if this is still working but if not I will be updating the code when an upgrade occurs

Comment: Thanks!! @JulioBailon

Comment: @JulioBailon is the latest Swift code still working in iOS 12? Also, does it require NSObject extension mentioned for an earlier update?

Answer (score 25):

Try this code.

```
    UIResponder* responder = self;
    while ((responder = [responder nextResponder]) != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"responder = %@", responder);
        if([responder respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:)] == YES)
        {
            [responder performSelector:@selector(openURL:) withObject:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is this working, by the way? I thought extension can not get instance of the current running app.

Comment: This is blocking extension from getting terminated :(

Answer (score 19):

Worked solution in Swift 3.0 & 4.0:

```
// For skip compile error. 
func openURL(_ url: URL) {
    return
}

func openContainerApp() {
    var responder: UIResponder? = self as UIResponder
    let selector = #selector(openURL(_:))
    while responder != nil {
        if responder!.responds(to: selector) && responder != self {
            responder!.perform(selector, with: URL(string: "containerapp://")!)
            return
        }
        responder = responder?.next
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

In extension, api is limited by compiler to not let you use openURl(:URL) like in container app. However the api is still here.

And we can't perform method in our class until we declare it, what we really want is let UIApplication to perform this method.

Recall to responder chain, we can use

```
    var responder: UIResponder? = self as UIResponder
    responder = responder?.next
```

to loop to UIApplication object.

And my apps with this method pass the review process, so don't worry to use it.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This code works for my Safari Share extension. Any idea if this is ok by Apple? I'd like to get this into production if it's safe to use.

Comment: @timgcarlson got an answer yet? Or tested it yourself?

Comment: @Reiz3N It definitely works, but I have yet to submit an app with this code in there. I'm hesitant to do so since I've never seen another app do this.

Comment: @timgcarlson
Thanks for an answer, used this code snippet myself and it works great. Gonna use it in production app and see if Apple does have anything against it. If you'll publish yours earlier I would be grateful if you gave me a hint what they said about it ;)

Comment: i am using this code in my app, and pass apple's review.

Comment: i get following Compiler Error: Method 'openURL' with Objective-C selector 'openURL:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector

Comment: Great answer @AlenLiang but I have one concern of app store review process. Will the app have above implementation get approved?

Comment: @Kamarshad My app using the code above passed review.

Comment: @AlenLiang Thank you :)

Comment: Awesome ! , This answer working in Swift 4 as well .

Comment: @Basil, it's not working on iOS 13. Any workaround ?

Comment: XCode 11.5 "Use of unresolved identifier 'openURL'"

Answer (score 18):

Apple accepted the following solution, which is the "same" code that a host app would use. It works on all iOS 8 versions to date (tested on iOS 8.0 - iOS 8.3).

```
NSURL *destinationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myapp://"];

// Get "UIApplication" class name through ASCII Character codes.
NSString *className = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:(unsigned char []){0x55, 0x49, 0x41, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E} length:13] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
if (NSClassFromString(className)) {
    id object = [NSClassFromString(className) performSelector:@selector(sharedApplication)];
    [object performSelector:@selector(openURL:) withObject:destinationURL];
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this on iOS 9 ?

Comment: @SebastienLorber just tested on iOS 9 and this solution still works. There is the caveat that now iOS 9 displays confirmation messages before switching apps, so running this code will first show a confirmation dialog asking: **Open "MyApp"?**

Comment: by chance, can you explain your solution a bit (I mean the ASCII characters mostly)? And maybe provide a similar Swift solution?  see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153626/cant-translate-objective-c-snippet-to-swift

Answer (score 11):

**Working solution (tested on iOS 9.2)** for Keyboard Extension. This category adds special method for access to hidden `sharedApplication` object and then call `openURL:` on it.
(Of course then you have to use `openURL:` method with your app scheme.)

```
extension UIInputViewController {

    func openURL(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        do {
            let application = try self.sharedApplication()
            return application.performSelector("openURL:", withObject: url) != nil
        }
        catch {
            return false
        }
    }

    func sharedApplication() throws -> UIApplication {
        var responder: UIResponder? = self
        while responder != nil {
            if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
                return application
            }

            responder = responder?.nextResponder()
        }

        throw NSError(domain: "UIInputViewController+sharedApplication.swift", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: I was lucky enough to read every solution, and yours worked fine

Comment: You are welcome! You can also find useful my second approach described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495362/launch-containing-app-from-ios8-custom-keyboard/34426798#34426798

Answer (score 10):

Following code works on **Xcode 8.3.3, iOS10, Swift3** and **Xcode 9, iOS11, Swift4** without any compiler warnings:

```
func openUrl(url: URL?) {
    let selector = sel_registerName("openURL:")
    var responder = self as UIResponder?
    while let r = responder, !r.responds(to: selector) {
        responder = r.next
    }
    _ = responder?.perform(selector, with: url)
}

func canOpenUrl(url: URL?) -> Bool {
    let selector = sel_registerName("canOpenURL:")
    var responder = self as UIResponder?
    while let r = responder, !r.responds(to: selector) {
        responder = r.next
    }
    return (responder!.perform(selector, with: url) != nil)
}
```

Make sure your app supports Universal Links, otherwise it will open the link in browser. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: it is not working for me with Custom Share Extension UI (directly subclassed `UIViewController`) with xcode 9, swift 3 and iOS 10.3.1

Comment: @KauthamMurugan, just checked, works fine on xcode 9, swift 4 and iOS 11.

Comment: Have you replace the `SLComposeServiceViewController` to `UIViewController`in the ShareViewController ? I think that should be the problem, but i am not sure.

Comment: @KauthamMurugan, yes, I am subclassing `UIViewController` in ShareViewController. Not using `SLComposeServiceViewController`.

Comment: Can confirm this code not working on XCode 9.1 (gist: https://gist.github.com/broskoski/5de3da49de3ae9add1e0f71f6c6e08fd)

Comment: doesn't work for me.  Mine is an ActionViewController: UIViewController

Comment: @horseshoe7 it still works for me. Probably you are doing something else wrong or you have different config somewhere.

Comment: If it doesn't work, probably you app is not supporting universal app links properly. Read here about here more: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: This code worked for me flawlessly in iMessage extension. Tested on iOS 13. I opened app store review URL with this code. Thank you!

Comment: I'm using Swift 5.4 with Xcode 12.5 and this code WORKED for me! Thanks @DenissFedotovs

Answer (score 7):

It seems to be a bug, because docs say:

> **Opening the Containing App**
>
> In some cases, it can make sense for an extension to request its
>   containing app to open. For example, the Calendar widget in OS X opens
>   Calendar when users click an event. To ensure that your containing app
>   opens in a way that makes sense in the context of the user’s current
>   task, you need to define a custom URL scheme that both the app and its
>   extensions can use.
>
> An extension doesn’t directly tell its containing app to open;
>   instead, it uses the openURL:completionHandler: method of
>   NSExtensionContext to tell the system to open its containing app. When
>   an extension uses this method to open a URL, the system validates the
>   request before fulfilling it.

I reported it today: http://openradar.appspot.com/17376354 You should dupe it, if you have some free time.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that you occur the same problem. What do you mean for “dupe”? Do you mean I should add comment at your bug reports?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. You should report it at https://bugreport.apple.com and in *Additional Notes* field write: `It's a duplicate of rdar://17376354`. The more bug reports point to the issue, the better is the chance of Apple fixing it.

Comment: I managed to do the steps as you mentioned, haha. I also wrote to evangelist of Apple which is shown in the end of the WWDC extension video. Hope Apple could give us some response.

Comment: Do you have any progress? The evangelist has not response to me.

Comment: @LaurenceFan: Not yet. I guess we have to give them some more time.

Comment: Apple has changed its documentation:  `In some cases, it can make sense for a Today widget to request its containing app to open.`

Answer (score 7):

NSExtensionContext only support openURL function in today extension ,this is described in apple's documents about NSExtensionContext.The original words is "Each extension point determines whether to support this method, or under which conditions to support this method. In iOS 8.0, only the Today extension point supports this method."

Answer (score 6):

A possible workaround:
Create and add a small UIWebView to your view and run it's method loadRequest with the url scheme you set above.
This is a workaround and I'm not sure what Apple will say about it.
Good luck!

Comment: nice to see this answer! My leader also suggest this workaround. I have try this and let the UIWebView run a javaScript to automatically simulate the "click the jump link" action. And I can do it successfully.

Comment: It remind me that maybe Apple will not allow such behavior. As @IanBaird mentioned, it seems Apple really not approve it. And I voted your answer. But I think we can not resolve this problem now. Do you think so?

Comment: @LaurenceFan - I am waiting for an official Apple response regarding this API validity - will update!

Comment: Hi @nurne, Do you see Ian Baird's answer? Do you think the answer is correct? Hope your thread will be answered by Apple staff or someone else.

Comment: @LaurenceFan Has anyone submitted an app yet using this workaround? I'd be interested to know whether Apple accepted it.

Comment: @MatthewGertner We do not use extension in the end. Since our manager think there are other things more important than implement the extension of our app. Thanks for asking the question.

Comment: This functionality broke in iOS 8.3.

Comment: We got it accepted in an app but i confirm @HankBrekke finding. It does not work since 8.3

Answer (score 6):

An updated version of Julio Bailon's answer with modern Swift syntax:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "scheme://")!
var responder: UIResponder? = self
while let r = responder {
    if r.respondsToSelector("openURL:") {
        r.performSelector("openURL:", withObject: url)
        break
    }
    responder = r.nextResponder()
}
```

There is no need for an extension for NSObject now.

Note: you must wait for the view to be attached to the view hierarchy before calling this code otherwise the responder chain can't be used.

Comment: Thanks for this - I've got about 3 hours experience with Swift and iOS so this is really helpful :)

Comment: "Note: you must wait for the view to be attached to the view hierarchy before calling this code otherwise the responder chain can't be used." This is very important. I wasted a lot of time until I realized calling from viewDidLoad won't work but viewWillAppear did work.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for the latest iOS SDK 10.2. All previous solutions use deprecated api. This solution is based on searching UIApplication UIResponder of the hosting application (This app which create execution context for our extension). The solution can only be provided in Objective-C because there is a 3 arguments method to invoke and this is impossible to do with `performSelector:` methods. To invoke this not deprecated method `openURL:options:completionHandler:` we need to use NSInvocation instance which is unavailable in Swift. The provided solution can be invoked from Objective-C and Swift (any version). I need to say that I don't know yet if provided solution will be valid for apple review process.

`UIViewController+OpenURL.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIViewController (OpenURL)
- (void)openURL:(nonnull NSURL *)url;
@end
```

`UIViewController+OpenURL.m`

```
#import "UIViewController+OpenURL.h"

@implementation UIViewController (OpenURL)

- (void)openURL:(nonnull NSURL *)url {

    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"openURL:options:completionHandler:");

    UIResponder* responder = self;
    while ((responder = [responder nextResponder]) != nil) {
        NSLog(@"responder = %@", responder);
        if([responder respondsToSelector:selector] == true) {
            NSMethodSignature *methodSignature = [responder methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
            NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:methodSignature];

            // Arguments
            NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *options = [NSDictionary dictionary];
            void (^completion)(BOOL success) = ^void(BOOL success) {
                NSLog(@"Completions block: %i", success);
            };

            [invocation setTarget: responder];
            [invocation setSelector: selector];
            [invocation setArgument: &url atIndex: 2];
            [invocation setArgument: &options atIndex:3];
            [invocation setArgument: &completion atIndex: 4];
            [invocation invoke];
            break;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

From Swift 3 You can execute this only if Your view controller is in view hierarchy. This is the code how I'm using it:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let context = self.extensionContext!
        let userAuthenticated = self.isUserAuthenticated()

        if !userAuthenticated {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "User not logged in", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
                context.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)
            }
            let login = UIAlertAction(title: "Log In", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                //self.openContainingAppForAuthorization()
                let url = URL(string: "fashionapp://login")!
                self.open(url)
                context.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)
            })

            alert.addAction(cancel)
            alert.addAction(login)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does really work! Tested Xcode 8.3.1 + swift 3 + iPhone 5s + iOS 10.3.2

Comment: From share extension app click in iOS 13.1.3, it's not working. Do you have a fix ?

Answer (score 2):

A bit safer option using recursion

```
func handleUrl(_ hostUrl: URL?) {
        fileUrl.map { URL(string: yourUrlSchemeId + "://" + $0.absoluteString) }.map { finalUrl in
            let selector = #selector(openURL(_:))
            func proccessNext(_ responder: UIResponder?) {
                responder.map {
                    if $0.responds(to: selector) {
                        $0.perform(selector, with: finalUrl)
                    } else {
                        proccessNext($0.next)
                    }
                }
            }
            proccessNext(self.next)
        }
    }
    @objc func openURL(_ url: URL) {
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not every app extension type supports "extensionContext openURL".

I tested on iOS 8 beta 4 and found Today extension supports it, but keyboard extension does not.

Comment: Right but nowhere does it say what types support it

Answer (score 0):

Only the Today Extension seems to work.
It's not 100% documented, but an apple employee specifically says that Keyboard extensions do not support openURL:completionHandler.
The documentation says:

> Each extension point determines whether to support this method, or under which conditions to support this method.

So in practice, Share, Action, Keyboard, and Document provider do **not** work for anyone (beta 5) and only Today Extension supports it.

Answer (score 0):

As apple document
" A Today widget (and no other app extension type) can ask the system to open its containing app by calling the openURL:completionHandler: method of the NSExtensionContext class."

For other Extension, I used this solution

```
UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
NSString *urlString = @"ownApp://"; // Use other application url schema.

NSString * content = [NSString stringWithFormat : @"<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=%@'></head>", urlString];
[webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that this is intentionally not possible. The `openURL:completionHandler:` block says that it may not be supported in all extension types, and the action extension docs explicitly say:

> If you want to help users share content on a social website or give users updates on information they care about, the Action extension point is not the right choice.

I think a share extension might be more appropriate, but the docs for both types suggest that the experience should be embedded in the host app, not taking the users to your app, so it might not allow that for that either. So, perhaps follow the share extension docs and just upload your image from within the extension UI as it suggests?

Comment: I read Apple document again and could not found about "both types suggest that the experience should be embedded in the host app". Where did you saw it? Or could you kindly paste the original words in the Apple document and I can search them via Google? :)

Comment: @LaurenceFan "When users choose your Share extension, you display a view in which they compose their content and post it" and "In iOS, an Action extension... Always appears in an action sheet or full-screen modal view". Note that neither say anything about launching the host app; it's certainly not explicit, though.

Comment: I think I understand your meaning and I found such words in document. Thanks a lot. We need modify the image and do some business logic, so just use Share extension to upload the image is not enough. Do you think Apple will provide more explanation and examples?

Comment: @LaurenceFan You should be able to modify the image and perform business logic within the share extension. If there's some reason you can't, you should file a bug with Apple (or edit your existing one) explaining clearly *why* you need to be able to use openURL for  your use case.

Comment: I try to use "shared resource" to transfer gallery's image to my own app. I will learn from your suggestions and may file a bug if it is necessary.