# openURL from App Extension

Tags: ios8, uiapplication, openurl, ios-app-extension

On iOS 8 beta 2 it should be possible to use openUrl from app extension as written into the release notes:

[image]

however when I try to use this API (on Xcode 6 beta 2) I get the following error:

[image]

Beta 2 really fixed this issue or not?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

you may use this code:

```
[self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        NSLog(@"fun=%s after completion. success=%d", __func__, success);
    }];
```

the API document:
[openURL:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSExtensionContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSExtensionContext/openURL:completionHandler:)

you could also refer to this question:
[openURL not work in Action Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297273/openurl-not-work-in-action-extension)

Comment: @MassimoPiazza Which type Extension do you use when you add openURL sentence? I try it in Action extension but failed. I only success in Today extension. What result do you have?

Comment: @MassimoPiazza Got it. I am working on Action extension and openURL can not work. Wait for Apple's response.

Comment: I might add that this code worked inside an IBACtion for a button overlaid over the entire widget. Is there a way to do this without an invisible button?

Comment: Only Today Extensions support openUrl.  See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297273/openurl-not-work-in-action-extension

Answer (score 6):

**Accepted solution only works in `Today extensions`, a working solution in Swift 3.1 (tested in iOS10) for other extension-types:**

*You need to create your own URL Scheme*, then add this function to your ViewController and call it with `openURL("myScheme://myIdentifier")`

```
//  Function must be named exactly like this so a selector can be found by the compiler!
//  Anyway - it's another selector in another instance that would be "performed" instead.
func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
    var responder: UIResponder? = self
    while responder != nil {
        if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
            return application.perform(#selector(openURL(_:)), with: url) != nil
        }
        responder = responder?.next
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Do you have objective-C solution for this?

Comment: Sorry I can't deal with this. I found some ObjC to a similar problem which may help porting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495362/launch-containing-app-from-ios8-custom-keyboard

Comment: This is very useful for MacCatalyst applications. Thanks.