# launch containing app from iOS8 Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

I want to launch my containing app.

I tried using URL schemes.

The URL scheme launched the app from other places - so the problem is not there.

Looks like this object is nil:

```
   self.extensionContext
```

thus i can't run this method:

```
[self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
```

Can I launch my app? Do URL Schemes work in a custom keyboard?

thanks!

Comment: Have you got the solution of your problem ?

Comment: Check This Answer [Open My application from my keyboard extension in swift 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44718613/2150318)

Comment: https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/open-my-application-from-my-keyboard-extension-in-swift-3-0/21121/2?u=leangchhean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer MY OWN question:

In an iOS8 custom keyboard, the extensionContext object is nil, thus I can't use it to launch the containing app.

The workaround I came up with is:

1. create a url scheme for your app
2. add a UIWebView to your inputView
3. load the url scheme for your containing app in the webview

I'm not sure if Apple will allow this to happen, but it works now.

Comment: Does apple still allow this now? I can’t seem to get a UIWebView working inside the UIInputViewController. Let me know if it still works for you!

Comment: @ThE_-_BliZZarD make sure you enabled AllowFullAccess in the keyboard settings

Comment: @ThE_-_BliZZarD let us know if it helped!

Comment: @ThE_-_BliZZarD have you got the solution of above question ?

Comment: Ah sorry, I added this comment for a friend - and he then created his own account to add the answer below.
Therefore please look at the answer by Andi.

Comment: @BastienBeurier it looks like it doesn't work on the 8.3 beta1

Comment: App would be rejected if you open external app.  

As per apple review guideline section 4.4.1 see this: 

  > They must not:
  > Include marketing, advertising, or in-app purchases;
  > Launch other apps besides Settings; or

Answer (score 15):

Try this code

```
    UIResponder* responder = self;
    while ((responder = [responder nextResponder]) != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"responder = %@", responder);
        if([responder respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:)] == YES)
        {
            [responder performSelector:@selector(openURL:) withObject:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for me, opening URL Scheme doesn't work, opening Universal Links works fine.

Answer (score 11):

Here is **working solution (tested on iOS 9.2)** for Keyboard Extension. This category adds special method for access to hidden `sharedApplication` object and then call `openURL:` on it.
(Of course then you have to use `openURL:` method with your app scheme.)

```
// Usage:
// UIInputViewController.openURL(NSURL(string: "your-app-scheme://")!)
extension UIInputViewController {

    func openURL(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        do {
            let application = try self.sharedApplication()
            return application.performSelector("openURL:", withObject: url) != nil
        }
        catch {
            return false
        }
    }

    func sharedApplication() throws -> UIApplication {
        var responder: UIResponder? = self
        while responder != nil {
            if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
                return application
            }

            responder = responder?.nextResponder()
        }

        throw NSError(domain: "UIInputViewController+sharedApplication.swift", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
    }

}
```

Lately I developed slightly different approach:

```
// Usage:
// UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "your-app-scheme://")!)

extension UIApplication {

    public static func sharedApplication() -> UIApplication {
        guard UIApplication.respondsToSelector("sharedApplication") else {
            fatalError("UIApplication.sharedKeyboardApplication(): `UIApplication` does not respond to selector `sharedApplication`.")
        }

        guard let unmanagedSharedApplication = UIApplication.performSelector("sharedApplication") else {
            fatalError("UIApplication.sharedKeyboardApplication(): `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` returned `nil`.")
        }

        guard let sharedApplication = unmanagedSharedApplication.takeUnretainedValue() as? UIApplication else {
            fatalError("UIApplication.sharedKeyboardApplication(): `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` returned not `UIApplication` instance.")
        }

        return sharedApplication
    }

    public func openURL(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        return self.performSelector("openURL:", withObject: url) != nil
    }

}
```

Comment: That's strange, it works for me. Which approach have you tested?

Comment: I'm testing on 9.3.2 beta.

Comment: Oh, i've tested your secondary way and it works. Why do you have a rocket emoji on your method?

Comment: Uh, that's great! I am using  symbol here because I can, because I love emojis and because we cannot use names `openURL` or `sharedApplication` here because they exist but marked as `unavailable`.

Comment: Well, i asked because if i delete the rocket emoji. I've got this error : `Method 'sharedApplication()' with Objective-C selector 'sharedApplication' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector`

Comment: P.s: If we write this in latest swift syntax, it won't compile

Comment: @ValentinShergin would this work in the iMessage extensions?  I'm trying to figure out a way to perform an authentication that requires openURL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459871/how-to-handle-oauth-style-log-ins-with-imessage-apps-in-ios-10-xcode-8

Answer (score 5):

Apple does not allow any app extensions other than Today extensions to open the containing app.

From the guidelines:

> A Today widget (and no other app extension type) can ask the system to open its containing app by calling the openURL:completionHandler: method of the NSExtensionContext class.

You can check [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2)

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple's documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html, you should use NSExtensionContext like this:

```
NSExtensionContext *ctx = [[NSExtensionContext alloc] init];
[ctx openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myapp://"] completionHandler:^(BOOL success){return ;}];
```

Answer (score 2):

A Swift 2.2 version, akin to DongHyun Jang's answer for Objective-C:

```
func webLink(urlString: String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    var responder: UIResponder? = self
    while let r = responder {
        if r.respondsToSelector("openURL:") {
            r.performSelector("openURL:", withObject: url)
            break;
        }
        responder = r.nextResponder()
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do above solutions for latest xcode 8.2 and swift 3.0.

Unfortunately. I can't get it work. So I found my own solution and it works well in swift 3.0, xcode 8.2

```
   func openURL(_ url: URL) {
        return
   }

   func openApp(_ urlstring:String) {

       var responder: UIResponder? = self as UIResponder
       let selector = #selector(openURL(_:))
       while responder != nil {
           if responder!.responds(to: selector) && responder != self {
              responder!.perform(selector, with: URL(string: urlstring)!)
              return
             }
             responder = responder?.next
          }
   }

  // Usage
  //call the method like below
  //self.openApp(urlString)

  //URL string need to included custom scheme.
  //for example, if you created scheme name = customApp
  //urlString will be "customApp://?[name]=[value]"
  //self.openApp("customApp://?category=1")
```

Comment: This does not compile, throws error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'openURL'`. This works but is deprecated: `let selector: Selector = "openURL:"`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found to open any URL using what has been described above:

```
UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
NSString *urlString = @"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/watuu/id304697459";
NSString * content = [NSString stringWithFormat : @"<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=%@'></head>", urlString];
[webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

Please note that in this case I am instantiating this call from the UIInputViewController.

This method should also work using the URL scheme from the containing app

**NOTE: As of iOS 8.3 Apple has killed this method**

Answer (score 1):

In an App Extension (ex: custom keyboard), that would have been handled through `UIViewController.extensionContext` but as of iOS 8.1.2, the field is `nil` in the following Swift call:

```
self.extensionContext?.openURL(appURL, completionHandler: nil)
// Does nothing because extensionContext is nil (iOS 8.1)
```

Actually, it is not possible either to use `Application.sharedApplication.openURL(...)` in an App Extension as stated in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6).

So, as of 8.1.2, the workaround is to use a dumb `UIWebView` to redirect to the containing app like this:

```
let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0));
let url = "MyKeyboard://";
let content = "<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=\(url)'></head>";
webView.loadHTMLString(content, baseURL: nil);
self.view.addSubview(webView);
let delayInSeconds = 2.0
let startTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(startTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
    webView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Where `MyKeyboard://` must be defined accordingly as URL scheme in the containing app.

Please take note that I don't know yet whether this is approved by Apple. Forwarding to apps from custom keyboards may be bad enough for user experience.

Answer (score 1):

As per Apple review guidelines for Extension, it is now *not* advised to open external apps from the extension.

For reference please see [apple review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

Section 4.4.1

> They must not:
>
> - Include marketing, advertising, or in-app purchases;
> - **Launch other apps besides Settings; or**

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a couple of days. I could not get the UIWebView working inside the custom keyboard.

Fix: put it inside the viewDidAppear:animated instead of viewDidLoad (on another note this is where the code for the keyboard's custom height should stay as well).

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    NSString * content = @"<a href='your_app_schema://your_params'>anchor</a>";
    [webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Comment: I think it's annoying that everything ends up in viewDidAppear rather than viewDidLoad... What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

```
let selectorOpenURL = NSSelectorFromString("openURL:")
var responder: UIResponder? = self
while let r = responder {
    if r.canPerformAction(selectorOpenURL, withSender: nil) {
         r.perform(selectorOpenURL, with: url, afterDelay: 0.01)
         break
    }
    responder = r.next
}
```