# Open containing app from custom keyboard in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, custom-keyboard, uiapplication

Before iOS 10 i used the method written by Valentin Sherwin  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426798/6433023).
Any workarounds to open the containing app from the custom keyboard with Swift 3?

Answer (score 1):

please try to use below method. 
it worked well on xcode 8.2, swift 3.0

```
func openURL(_ url: URL) {
    return
}

func openApp(_ urlstring:String) {

    var responder: UIResponder? = self as UIResponder
    let selector = #selector(openURL(_:))
    while responder != nil {
        if responder!.responds(to: selector) && responder != self {
            responder!.perform(selector, with: URL(string: urlstring)!)
            return
        }
        responder = responder?.next
    }
}

// Usage
//call the method like below
// self.openApp(urlString)

// URL string need to included custom scheme.
// for example, if you created scheme name = customApp
// urlString will be "customApp://?[name]=[value]"
// self.openApp("customApp://?category=1")
```