# iOS Custom Keyboard App review check for launching another application

Tags: ios, swift, appstore-approval, custom-keyboard

I want to open my own application from the custom keyboard which is added using this app.

So far I see app review guidelines with details specified below, its said we cannot launch other apps.

However I see *Google Translator*, icici bank *iMobile* keyboards which allow to launch *YouTube* or their own banking app.

This is bit confusing and violating to the review understanding. Can an expert clarify here 'If I can launch the same app from which the keyboard is installed without facing apple rejection.

> 4.4.1 Keyboard extensions have some additional rules.
>
> **They must:**
>
> - Provide keyboard input functionality (e.g. typed characters);
> - Provide a method for progressing to the next keyboard;
> - Remain functional without full network access;
> - Provide Number and Decimal keyboard types as described in the App Extension Programming Guide;
> - Collect user activity only to enhance the functionality of the user’s keyboard extension on the iOS device.
>
> **They must not:**
>
> - Include marketing, advertising, or in-app purchases;
> - **Launch other apps besides Settings; or**
> - Repurpose keyboard buttons for other behaviors (e.g. holding down the <kbd>return</kbd> key to launch the camera.

Comment: you should be able to open your own app with keyboard extension. Your app will not be rejected, apple clearly mentions that you cannot open "other apps". If it's rejected you can file an appeal giving reference to above requirement - nowhere it's written that we cannot open our own app. Seen lot of apps doing that , here is link for your coding reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495362/launch-containing-app-from-ios8-custom-keyboard

Comment: Hi! Did you get your "containing-app-launching-keyboard" reviewed?

Comment: Yes the app got rejected and we were mentioned that the app doesn't Value add to the Apple's point of view for keyboard extension. This was annoying but there is not point to go ahead as this was the review community decision. Best option we did to dropout the idea loosing efforts and move to android which was swift and approved.