# Opening URL from Today Extension

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, osx-yosemite, today-extension

I am developing a cocoa app which is also using a Today extension for OSX Yosemite.

I have a button on the Today extension and I need it to open the main browser and a defined website.

I normally use

`[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];`

but this code is not working when it's used in the extension.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24297273/95309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/24357832/95309