# Open URL scheme from iOS extension

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

I have this code that return `success = NO`

```
[self.extensionContext openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URLApp://"] completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

     [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:nil completionHandler:nil];

 }];
```

So and I can't open containing app from my share extension when I debug it.

I've configured main target of contained app like this:

[image]

I've tested open `URLApp://` from safari and it works for me.

I also used some examples provided [here](http://atinyfish.com/2014/06/26/adding-a-url-scheme-to-your-app/) to understand how to open containing app using url scheme.

Comment: Possibly related Q&A: [openURL from App Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356314/openurl-from-app-extension).

Comment: You're using an URL with only a scheme. Have you tried a more valid URL? like `[NSURL URLWithString:@"URLApp://openApp"]`

Comment: @Marc-AlexandreBérubé i've answered my comment, what do you think. it works for me.

Comment: That method doesn't work because it's designed to not work in share extensions. The docs for the method say **In iOS 8, only the Today extension point (used for creating Today widgets) supports this method.**

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ok, just a little correction here. I got it working with placing a button over the label just like suggested above and the following code:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"floblog://"];
 [self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
```

I linked it to a "Touch Up Inside" event. However, this also causes the app to launch when the user scrolls the Today view.

=======================================

I ran into the same issue. However, it seems that there is no solution for now since the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/index.html) for the first beta of iOS 8 mention:

> Known Issues: openURL does not work from an extension.

So I guess we will at least have to wait until beta 2.

Comment: We're past iOS 8.0 Beta 2 for a while now. As of the date of this comment, the latest iOS version is 8.3. But I think the restriction (be it an issue or by design) still remains - haven't tested though.

Comment: @jweyrich i answered my question. what do you think?

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander does it solve your problem? If so, you may accept your own answer. I'd also recommend up-voting the original answer you used as reference. The guy deserves an incentive as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297273/openurl-not-work-in-action-extension) by Julio Bailon:

```
UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
NSString *urlString = @"URLApp://";
NSString * content = [NSString stringWithFormat : @"<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=%@'></head>", urlString];
[webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

Comment: Does that actually work for you? That answer is a few months old and [a more recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657857/ios-8-3-share-extension-launching-url-schemes) suggest that it doesn't work in newer versions of iOS.

Comment: @TomHarrington, hm omg, but what can be a solution? it's no so good, so in case if I don't have configured account I can use share extension to send data to server, so I want to say to user - "Open app to sign in". do you have any thoughts how to provide open app feature?

Comment: You don't. In the question you linked to, the person who wrote the accepted answer is one of the Apple engineers who developed app extensions. Apple doesn't want it to work that way and is closing down any workarounds that people find. File a bug with Apple and hope that they change it.