# How to launch a parent iOS App from its App Extension

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, today-extension, share-extension

Does any one know how to launch the parent app from the app extension's view controller?

I just want to launch the main app from its app extension.

Answer (score 11):

In the WWDC session [Creating Extensions for iOS and OS X, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=205) around the 22 minute mark the say to use the `openURL:completionHandler:` method from the UIViewController's [extensionContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/extensionContext) to open a [custom URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50)

```
[self.extensionContext openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your-app-custom-url-scheme://your-internal-url"]
             completionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: It definitely works for Today Extensions - I have it in an example on github:https://github.com/kmonaghan/CBPExtensionExample

Comment: Trying to do this from a keyboard, but it's not working.

Comment: Had to add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes array to info.plist of the extension for this to work

Comment: OpenUrl is working from share extension as well, but if host app is closed and I tried to share then AppDelegate is calling two methods FinishedLaunching with options and OpenUrl. Is there any way to handle this scenario?

Comment: The minimum shape of the url scheme seems to be to add a colon: `com.somedomain.appname:`. Removing the colon would not open the app. Tested on iOS 11.2.6.

Answer (score 11):

**Working solution in Swift 3.1 (tested in iOS10):**

*You need to create your own URL Scheme for your host app*, then add this function to your ViewController and call it with `openURL("myScheme://myIdentifier")`

```
//  Function must be named exactly like this so a selector can be found by the compiler!
//  Anyway - it's another selector in another instance that would be "performed" instead.
func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
    var responder: UIResponder? = self
    while responder != nil {
        if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
            return application.perform(#selector(openURL(_:)), with: url) != nil
        }
        responder = responder?.next
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: PLzz tell how it will be called via extension as this seems incomplete answer

Comment: There is really nothing special. In my case I have a shareextension consisting of only one ViewController. I put `openURL` inside that ViewController and just called `self.openURL(URL(string: "myapp://com.mydomain.share?urlparams")!)` after viewDidAppear. The ViewController itself is nearly empty - I just collect incoming files and save them into a local folder before I do the call above. Do not forget to register your URL scheme `myapp`...

Answer (score 9):

it is working in my current working app using action extension

1- in parent app plist add custom URL like
[image]

2- add both functions in your extension view controller

```
func openURL(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
    do {
        let application = try self.sharedApplication()
        return application.performSelector(inBackground: "openURL:", with: url) != nil
    }
    catch {
        return false
    }
}

func sharedApplication() throws -> UIApplication {
    var responder: UIResponder? = self
    while responder != nil {
        if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
            return application
        }

        responder = responder?.next
    }

    throw NSError(domain: "UIInputViewController+sharedApplication.swift", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
}
```

3- call this function in your button action or somewhere you want to do

```
self.openURL(url: NSURL(string:"openPdf://HomeVC")!)
```

here homevc is the class name of your View controller which should be presented

4- in your app delegate implement the method like

```
  func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let urlPath : String = url.absoluteString
    print(urlPath)
    if urlPath.contains("HomeVC"){
        //here go to firstViewController view controller
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeVC")

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

I hope will work fine, can also share data between extension app and parent app

Comment: For some reason it launches app and works without step 4. Moreover none of  `AppDelegate` methods `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool` or `func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                       continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                       restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool` fire.

Comment: step 4 will be used when you need to open the vc other then initail vc

Comment: Is there a reason for adding `URL Type` to `Info.plist`, not via project settings -> host target -> Info tab -> add  URL Type , @Awais?

Answer (score 3):

Here is `Valentin Shergin's` solution for **ios 14 & xcode 13**

```
extension KeyboardViewController{
    func openURL(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
            do {
                let application = try self.sharedApplication()
                return (application.perform("openURL:", with: url) != nil)
            }
            catch {
                return false
            }
        }

        func sharedApplication() throws -> UIApplication {
            var responder: UIResponder? = self
            while responder != nil {
                if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
                    return application
                }

                responder = responder?.next
            }

            throw NSError(domain: "UIInputViewController+sharedApplication.swift", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question here: [Communicating with/opening Containing app from Share extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25254700/3923882). Basically, you can do a couple things.

1. Use a UIWebView's loadRequest webView to load an NSURL request with your containing app's url. For example,

   ```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
   [self.webView loadRequest:request];
   ```
2. Use a UIDocumentInteractionController and a custom file extension type to provide a link to your containing app (and your containing app only)
3. Start a "fake" NSURL session to get the following functionality: In iOS, if your extension isn’t running when a background task completes, the system launches your containing app in the background and calls the application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler: app delegate method.

The first one is probably your best bet.

Comment: FWIW: I used this method and it worked in iOS 8.0 for sure, but at some point between then and now (perhaps 9.0, perhaps earlier), it stopped working :(

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is pretty clear on saying that you can use extensionContext openURL within a Today extension.  By implication, openURL can only be used in a Today exception and our experiences are proving this to be true--I also can't get it working from within a Share extension.

I would be interested to see if any of these work arounds are accepted by Apple's review process.  I doubt it.  If Apple wanted it to work, it would have been easy enough for them to allow it.

> Apple allows any Today widget to use the openURL:completionHandler:
>   method to open the widget’s own containing app.
>
> If you employ this method to open other apps from your Today widget,
>   your App Store submission might entail additional review to ensure
>   compliance with the intent of Today widgets.

I'm certain this second paragraph was added after Launcher was accepted, rejected, and then later approved for sale.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it:

1. [Step 1 from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60319786/)
2. Select extension target and go to its `Build Settings`. Set `Require Only App-Extension Safe API` to `NO`.
3. Use `UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"openPdf://")!)` as you normally would do it outside extension to open urls.

Note, that you'll get *'openURL' was deprecated in iOS 10.0 warning*. So this looks like it is not guaranteed to work in future.

Consider using local Notifications to wake up host app instead of this.

Comment: UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"openPdf://")!) instead of 
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"openPdf://")!)

Comment: I get this issue :
Application extensions and any libraries they link to must be built with the `APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY` build setting set to YES.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the extension needs it to use the API that this answer is about. I guess it worked before, I think it no longer works though.

Comment: Doesn't work on Shield Action extension. Same error as the above comment

Answer (score 1):

Here is **working solution (tested on iOS 9.2)** at least for Keyboard Extension. This category adds special method for access to hidden `sharedApplication` object and then call `openURL:` on it.
(Of course then you have to use `openURL:` method with your app scheme.)

```
extension UIInputViewController {

    func openURL(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        do {
            let application = try self.sharedApplication()
            return application.performSelector("openURL:", withObject: url) != nil
        }
        catch {
            return false
        }
    }

    func sharedApplication() throws -> UIApplication {
        var responder: UIResponder? = self
        while responder != nil {
            if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
                return application
            }

            responder = responder?.nextResponder()
        }

        throw NSError(domain: "UIInputViewController+sharedApplication.swift", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code in my extension to open the main app with a custom scheme url:

```
fileprivate func openUrl(url: URL?) {
    let selector = sel_registerName("openURL:")
    var responder = self as UIResponder?
    while let r = responder, !r.responds(to: selector) {
        responder = r.next
    }
    _ = responder?.perform(selector, with: url)
}
```

Make sure that the extension gets enough time to load before calling this function.