# Open extension from parent app programmatically iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-app-extension, imessage-extension

I want to **open my app's extension(an iMessage extension) programmatically from my parent iOS app,** let's say on a button tap for example.

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

I know [we can open parent app from extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727489/how-to-launch-a-parent-ios-app-from-its-app-extension),but my requirement is reverse.

I tried registering custom URL schema in extension target and tried to open with no luck.

Comment: Somehow it should be possible. App Store can do that.

Comment: @Are you able to do this ?

Comment: @Laszlo Appstore is Apple's own app, so ultimately we can expect it to have so many other benefits that we(3rd party devs) won't have, i believe Apple can do so many things with the private/internal APIs which are not exposed to us.

Comment: @AliPasha i was not able to achieve that at the time of my requirement, had to skip that and move on, not sure about the possibilities now.