# iOS action extension cannot open containing app

Tags: ios

I need to pass data from **A app** to **B app**. **A app** has provided **UTI**, and I am developing **B app**.

I can only use the way as shown below.
[image]

I understand that this method should be implemented using the action extension, but I cannot open the **B app** (contianing app) when I click the action extension.

I have looked for many ways, but none of them work,these are as follows:

```
responder?.perform(Selector("openURL:"), with: url)
```

```
[self.extensionContext openURL:YOUR_NSURL completionHandler:nil];
```

Is there any better suggestion to realize the transfer of data as shown in the figure above?

Answer (score 0):

I got inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895093/openurl-doesnt-work-in-share-extension), although using it directly did not get what I wanted.

Pay attention to two key points:

1. Must use Action type: `Presents User Interface`
2. Based on `ActionViewController`, recursively find `UIApplication`

Maybe you have also seen it, just click on the `Action Extension` to jump to the `Containing App`. If you use the type `Presents User Interface` directly, isn't there a page? But in fact I haven't seen this page. Because after executing `openURL`, directly `self.extensionContext?.completeRequest`, this page is closed below, it looks like it has never appeared. Here is the code:

```swift
func openApp(url: URL) {
      var responder = self as UIResponder?
      responder = (responder as? UIViewController)?.parent
      while (responder != nil && !(responder is UIApplication)) {
         responder = responder?.next
      }
      if responder != nil{
         let selectorOpenURL = sel_registerName("openURL:")
         if responder!.responds(to: selectorOpenURL) {
            responder!.perform(selectorOpenURL, with: url)
         }
     }
 }
```

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    let scheme = "xxapp://"
    let url: URL = URL(string: scheme)!
    openApp(url: url)
        
    self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
}
```