# Is there anyway of opening the container app from an app extension in iOS 8.3?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard, openurl

I have all the editing functionality in the container app of my keyboard extension, and I have a button to open the container app on the keyboard. I was using these methods [openURL not work in Action Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297273/openurl-not-work-in-action-extension)
However, in iOS8.3 apple changed his mind again. And, I cannot find a way to open the container app. 
Has anyone any idea how to do it? Please, help!

Comment: However, you can do that on **WatchKit Extension**

Answer (score 0):

Apple hasn't changed its mind on this even once, let alone "again". Only today extensions support opening their containing app, others do not. The workarounds that people found were-- from Apple's perspective-- bugs that were fixed.

There is no supported way to do what you want. If you find some workaround, you should expect it to disappear in the next iOS update.