# Open system settings to Add New Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I know it is possible to open up your app's own settings:

```
if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
else {
    // Present some dialog telling the user to open the settings app.
}
```

However, I need to open up a screen in the system settings. Specifically this one (the screen that contains the "Add New Keyboard" button, or even better, the screen right after that screen):

[image: settingsdemo]

What do I need to do to implement this functionality in a button? (Answers in swift or objective-C are fine)

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388317/open-keyboards-settings-screen-in-ioss-settings-app-programmatically-from-anot