# Can imessage extension open host app?

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios-extensions, ios10, imessage

I've tried `[self.extensionContext openURL:completion]`, but my app crashed. I heard some extensions can't use this method, can iMessage extensions?

By the way, can host app activate its iMessage extension?

Comment: Check this answer [Open My application from my keyboard extension in swift 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44718613/2150318)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`This is apparently not working in Seed 2 but should be fixed in Seed 3.`

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/153441#153441

Comment: It's not that it's not working. They're not meant to function in this manner. This should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: `i just did a test. now you can open host app from iMessage extension on beta 4`

Answer (score 6):

> Share Extensions and Action Extensions are not designed to function as app launchers.

[App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2)

There is no direct communication between an app extension and its containing app; typically, the containing app isn’t even running while a contained extension is running. An app extension’s containing app and the host app don’t communicate at all.

The extension displays a user interface, performs some work, and, if appropriate for the extension’s purpose, returns data to the host.

There is limited interaction available between an app extension and its containing app. **A Today widget (and no other app extension type)** can ask the system to open its containing app by calling the `openURL:completionHandler:` method of the `NSExtensionContext` class. "

[image]

A work around derived from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297273/openurl-not-work-in-action-extension).

Working solution (**tested on iOS 9.2**) for Keyboard Extension.

This category adds special method for access to **hidden** `sharedApplication` object and then call `openURL:` on it. (Of course then you have to use `openURL:` method with your app scheme.)

```
// Valentin Shergin

extension UIInputViewController {

func openURL(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
    do {
        let application = try self.sharedApplication()
        return application.performSelector("openURL:", withObject: url) != nil
    }
    catch {
        return false
    }
}

func sharedApplication() throws -> UIApplication {
    var responder: UIResponder? = self
    while responder != nil {
        if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
            return application
        }

        responder = responder?.nextResponder()
    }

    throw NSError(domain: "UIInputViewController+sharedApplication.swift", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, so i can not use `openURL:completion` in my messages extension?

Comment: Not the completion but you can use that very short extension to access the hidden `sharedApplication` object and then call `openURL` on it. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Has anyone gotten an app that uses this extension (or the swift3 version from @vmeyer) into the app store?  It's all well and good if it's technically possible, but if apple disallows the app because of it, it doesn't really help.

Comment: Does this allow people to open urls from message extensions?

Answer (score 2):

`self.extensionContext?.open(url, completionHandler: nil)` doesn't work in my iMessage extension.

tymac answer is correct, however openURL has been moved to open in Swift 3.

I found a simpler solution in this thread : [openURL not work in Action Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28037297/4320246)

```
extension UIViewController {

  func openURL(url: URL) {
    var responder = self as UIResponder?

    while (responder != nil){
      if responder?.responds(to: Selector("openURL:")) == true{
        responder?.perform(Selector("openURL:"), with: url)
      }
      responder = responder!.next
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: We just need it updated for the `#selector` syntax.

Answer (score -1):

This works fine for me:

```
NSString *customURL = @"myHostAppName://";

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
    } else {

        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"URL error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No custom URL defined for %@", customURL] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:ok];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Remember re-install the host app again.

Take in consideration [How to open our app from iMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630252/how-to-open-our-app-from-imessage)

Answer (score -2):

```
[self.extensionContext openURL:YOUR_NSURL completionHandler:nil];
```

it would be nice if you can pass deeplinks to open specific screen in app