# How to open our app from iMessage

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, url-scheme, imessage

I had created an app in iMessage that is work perfactly but i want to know how  can i open our app from iMessage

Suppose I have one app after that i added iMessage target and from iMessage I want to open my app from iMessage is it possible ?

I tried with this but not succeed

```
 NSString *customURL = @"appName://";

 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
 {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
  }
```

Error :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally Problem solved. I've been to the Build Settings of my app again and stumbled over

[image]

First time i set to YES. The default though is NO. When I set this to NO the error disappeared. i am also shocked with this results

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a main App already working (besides the iMessage extension).

Go to your main app's Info.plist create a new URL Types structure like this

URL Types -> URL Schemes -> Your_App_Name_No_Spaces

After this you can go to your app extension

```
NSString *customURL = @"appName://";

 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
 {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your subclass of MSMessagesAppViewController, there is a property extensionContext, of type NSExtensionContext. That object can open URLs for you.