# Swift: Unable to open url from extensioncontext in uiCollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, url, imessage-extension

Alright Im building a message extension app with a uicollectionview with header and footer. After several tries I learned why I wasn't able to open a url from the message controller using normal syntax - because its an extension it should use:

```
  let url: URL = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!
    self.extensionContext?.open(url, completionHandler: { (success: Bool) in
        print("hi")
    })
```

And this COMPILES but does not work in the MessageViewController file. I don't know why, but then in my

```
class FooterCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {
```

this does not compile even. I get the error
[image]

How can I open a url from my footer in my message extension? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling extensionContext on your `FooterCollectionReusableView`.
`extensionContext` is a property of `UIViewController`, so if you want to reference it from a view you would need to keep a reference to the parent view controller's extensionContext, or [create a protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) that would allow you to call the parent view controller to do whatever you need to be done with the extensionContext.

Comment: Yes but the problem is the url doesn't open even in the messageviewcontroller - it just completes the completion block, but doesnt open safari

Comment: It might be because the Today extension is technically the only extension that’s supposed to open other apps. This question would be more specific http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319433/can-imessage-extension-open-host-app